# hide datagridview column and Index

Tags: c#, datagridview

When using code to hide a `DataGridViewColumn`, does it affect the column index?

For example when:

- `column1` (index = `0`)
- `column2` (index = `1`)
- `column3` (index = `2`)

If I hide `column2`, does `column3` still use index (`2`)?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. could you explain your problem more with some code if possible? Your question doesn't provide enough informations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the `Visible` property to hide `column2` then:

- **No.** This will not affect indexing.

If you are temporarily *removing* `column2` then:

- **Yes.** Indexing will change.

---

Example:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "column3";

this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
Console.WriteLine(this.dataGridView1.Columns["column3"].Index);
// Output: 2

this.dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
Console.WriteLine(this.dataGridView1.Columns["column3"].Index);
// Output: 1
```